# When move between two layout ViewSwitcher giving NullPointerException, and how do i fix if?

Tags: java, android

I'm using ViewSwitcher to move between two layout and if user switch multiple time app is crashing and giving `java.lang.NullPointerException`.This error gives when user move landscape to portrait also via and switch multiple time switch between two layout.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Display d =getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final int w = d.getWidth();
        final int h = d.getHeight();
        final double ar = w > h ? (double) w / (double) h : (double) h / (double) w;

        this.container = container;
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote_port, container, false);
        viewSwitcher =(ViewSwitcher)rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_viewswitcher);

        if (ar > 1.6) {
            Log.i(TAG, "AR = " + ar + ", using extended layout.");
            remoteGesture = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remoteGesture_extended, null);
            remoteNav = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remoteNav_extended, null);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "AR = " + ar + ", normal layout.");
            remoteGesture = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remoteGesture, null);
            remoteNav = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remoteNav, null);
        }

        viewSwitcher.addView(remoteNav);
        viewSwitcher.addView(remoteGesture);
        setupButtons(rootView);
        return rootView;

    }
```

I'm using onConfigurationChanged method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    viewSwitcher.removeAllViews();
    container=(ViewGroup) getView();
    //rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote_port, container, false);
    //viewSwitcher =(ViewSwitcher)rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_viewswitcher);
    Display d =getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final int w = d.getWidth();
    final int h = d.getHeight();
    final double ar = w > h ? (double) w / (double) h : (double) h / (double) w;

    if (ar > 1.6) {
        Log.i(TAG, "AR = " + ar + ", using extended layout.");
        remoteGesture = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remoteGesture_extended, null);
        remoteNav = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remoteGesture, null);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "AR = " + ar + ", normal layout.");
        remoteGesture = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remoteGesture, null);
        remoteNav = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote, null);
    }

    viewSwitcher.addView(remoteNav);
    viewSwitcher.addView(remoteGesture);
    setupButtons(rootView);

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

I'm switching the two layout like this

```
 private void setupGestureButton(View button){
    if(button == null) return;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setupButtons(viewSwitcher.getNextView());
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the NullPointerException that I got from the Error log

```
12-17 10:49:58.104  17217-17217/au.com.bo.android.eco E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: au.com.bo.android.eco, PID: 17217
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at au.com.bo.android.eco.remotecontroller.RemoteFragment.setUpTouchPad(RemoteFragment.java:406)
        at au.com.bo.android.eco.remotecontroller.RemoteFragment.setupButtons(RemoteFragment.java:305)
        at au.com.bo.android.eco.remotecontroller.RemoteFragment.access$100(RemoteFragment.java:45)
        at au.com.bo.android.eco.remotecontroller.RemoteFragment$2.onClick(RemoteFragment.java:358)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4626)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19221)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace